# DataProtectorTokenProvider single use configuration

Tags: .net, token, forgot-password, reset-password

I'm trying to generate token to reset password and send it to user email using ASP .NET.
However, after verifying, user can click on the same link again and it still returns true. I want to config to Single use only.
This is where the code is generated

```
var code = await identityUserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id); //the code is generated here
```

This is where the code is verified

```
UserManager.VerifyUserToken(userId, "ResetPassword", code) //still return true after second click in Email
```

Please help me! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two ways to solve this problem :-**

*By following method 1, we implement expiry time with token. Here, user would still be able to double use the code, **if** expiry time is more that required. Better solution would be to put some `RouteGuards`, as shown in method 2. Doing so, will **not** allow user to visit the reset password page for the second time, **without** generation new code. So, here the user will be able to use the code only once. But, that one use will be without expiry*

**So, To have both benefits, I recommend to implement both** So that user will be able to use code only once, and that too before expiry time.

**Method 1 - (Implement Expire Time for Token)**

Create a database that has 3 column (TokenCode, IssuedToEmailId, ExpireTime) to store the same, with EmaildId as primary key, so that no more that one token can be issued to user at one time., and just after generating token in the `ForgetPassword()` provided below, delete any previous row in the table of this user, and insert new data -> the token code, email id of user, and expiry time, i.e., let's say `Datetime.Now.AddMinutes(10);`

And In `ResetPassword()` provided below, retrieve the data from table using email Id, and compare `Datetime.Now < ExpireTime` if true, proceed, else show expired code error.

**Method 2 - (Implement Route Guard)**

My code flow for Password Reset is that, on forget password page I ask for email address only, then, let's a button click start the process of token generation, email sending, etc. So, after successfully sending email, I do `return Ok()`, and start a session in `sessionStorage` & navigate to reset password page. Now, once here, I check for availability of same session, if not found, I nderstand that it had been removed and i navigate user to wherever I desire, But if the session is present, I ask for code new password, confirm new password, and then, lets's say a button click starts the process of password reset and on its `return Ok()`, I remove that session.

So, In case user tries to use same token again by visiting the reset password url, he does't have that session and so, gets navigated to wherever I want.
In this way, I don't need to verify user token.

**Codes =>**

Forget Password Code :-

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            // If user has to activate his email to confirm his account, the use code listing below
            //if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            //{
            //    return Ok();
            //}
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send an email with this link
            string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password for AJWebApp", $"Please reset your password by using this => {code}");
            return Ok();
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
```

Reset Password Code :-

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
            return Ok();
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```